# converting time into seconds+mili seconds

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file which contains a column "Time" which comprises of data in the format "01/02/2016 08:01:29;12", So now I want to separate this into two columns. Can anyone suggest me how to do that in python.

I am successfull in splitting the columns, but now i want to convert the time part(08:01:29;12) into seconds. I have written a function but it seems its not working, please help!

def time_convert(x):
    times = x.split(':')
    time = x.split(";")
    return (60*int(times[0])+60*int(times[1]))+int(times[2])+int(time[3])

Comment: use `.str.split(expand=True)` on the column

Comment: Thanks Edchum, it seems to work for me!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that ";12" in your date are microseconds, and that you want to separate date and time into two columns (if I understood correctly) it would be the best to convert str to datetime:

```
data = "01/02/2016 08:01:29;12"
actual_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(data, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S;%f")
```

and then you can access both date and time part of that datetime object.